# JS functions on multiple files. Create a class or use Webpack and Babel?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, webpack, babeljs

My Javascript project has 2 JS files(lets assume `abc.js`, `def.js`) and a html file(`index.html`). In `abc.js` file I have globally declared an array called `inputGraph[]`. Also in `abc.js` file I have a method called `assignValues()` which is used for assigning values to `inputGraph[]` array. I have another method in the same file called `getInputGraph()` which returns inputGraph array. In index.html file, I import above js files and inside `<script></script>` tags I call `assignValues()` and `getInputGraph()`(I use `getInputGraph()` to get the `inputGraph` array to `index.html`) respectively. I want to know about is the way I'm using those methods is right? Since I'm using `inputGraph` array just like an Object do I need to create a class for it or do I need to use Webpack with Babel or Parcel since there are more JS files.

abc.js

```
 var inputGraph=[];

    function assignValues(){
       for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
          inputGraph.push(i);
       }
    }

function getInputGraph(){
   return this.inputGraph;
}
```

def.js

```
//some ither functions
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <script src="./abc.js"></script>
      <script src="./def.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
         var graphArray = [];
         assignValues();
         graphArray = getInputGraph();
         console.log(graphArray );
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a globally declared ...... is the way I'm using these methods is right?

No. The moment you said "globally" you lost.

---

It would indeed make sense in this case to use a class to encapsulate your `graphArray`, `assignValue()` and `getInputGraph()` properties

Something to this effecft:

```
class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.graphArray = [];
  }

  assignValues() {
    // do something to this.graphArray
    // for example:
    this.graphArray.push({x: 42, y: 57});
  }

  getInputGraph() {
    // return a new graph array
    return [{x: 43, y: 58}];
  }
}

// usage
const graph = new Graph();
graph.graphArray = graph.getInputGraph();
graph.assignValues();
console.log(graph.graphArray); // [{x: 43, y:58}, {x: 42, y: 57}];
```

You don't strictly need to use webpack or Babel, but they give you some advantages that are usually hard to ignore in production projects:

- You get a single bundled file instead of a few files, so you only need to have one `<script src=>` element, and the client doesn't need to perform many requests.
- You get a file that will work even in browsers that do not support classes (i.e. IE11)
- You get minification
- You get resolution of dependencies (you can install dependencies using `npm`)